# Sticky navigation bar's responsiveness being dependent upon scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, navigationbar

I have achieved to make the navigation bar of my web page sticky and responsive but with an issue. In the very beginning when the screen is shrunk and hamburger icon is clicked the whole navigation bar shifts to the left, when I scroll the page even a little bit then it works totally fine, why is that happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Careers</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<style>
 body, html{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 line-height: 150%;
 color: #666;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Add bg color to topnav*/
.topnav{
 background: #333;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}

/*Style links inside navbar*/
.topnav a{
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}

/*Change link color on hover*/
.topnav a:hover{
 background: #ddd;
 color: black;
}

/*Add an active class to highlight the current page*/
.active{
 background: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}

/*Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens*/
.topnav .icon{
 display: none;
}

/*When the screen is less than 600px wide, hide all the links, except for the first one("Home").
Show the link that should open and close the topnav(.icon)*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 .topnav a:not(:first-child){display: none;}
 .topnav a.icon{
  float: right;
  display: block;
 }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon.
This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 .topnav.responsive{
  position: fixed;
 }
 .topnav.responsive .icon{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 .topnav.responsive a{
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
 }
}

/*The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position*/
.sticky{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.parallax1{
 background: url("img/joinUs3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 min-height: 80%;

}

.parallax2{
 background: url("img/notSure3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 min-height: 60%;
}

.parallax3{
 background: url("img/culture3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 min-height: 60%;
}

.parallax4{
 background: url("img/rightEmployee3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 min-height: 80%;
}

.parallax1, .parallax2, .parallax3, .parallax4{
 position: relative;
 opacity: .8;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

.heading{
 position: absolute;
 color: #fffaf7;
 font-size: 550%;
 font-weight: 700;
 top: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px #f96f1b;
 line-height: 1.1;
}

.heading2{
 position: absolute;
 color: #fffaf7;
 font-size: 250%;
 font-weight: 700;
 top: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px #f96f1b;
 line-height: 1.1; 
}

section{
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 50px 80px;
}
</style>

<!--Navigation Bar -->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <a href="#home">Home</a>
 <a href="#career" class="active">Careers</a>
 <a href="#fellowship">About Us</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
 </a>
 <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>



<!--Parallax-->
<div class="parallax1">
 <div class="heading">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </div>
</div>

<section class="dark">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
 </p>
</section>
<div class="parallax2">
 <div class="heading2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply. 
 </div>
</div>

<section class="dark">
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
 <div class="not-sure-sec">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 </div>
</section>

<div class="parallax3">
 <div class="heading2">
  Lorem Ipsum is.
 </div>
</div>

<section class="dark">
 <section class="culture">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2> 
 </section>
 <section class="insta">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </section>
 <section class="facebook">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </section>
</section>

<div class="parallax4"> 
 <div class="heading2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply
 </div>
</div>

<div class="dark">
 <section class="apply">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3> 
 </section>
 <section class="linkedin">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </section>
 <section class="contact-us">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </section>
</div>

<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 
 window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);
 var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
 
 function myFunctionForSticky() {
    
     if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky");
     } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
     }
   }

  var icon = document.querySelector("a.icon");
  icon.addEventListener("click",function(){
   navbar.classList.toggle("responsive");
  })

})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just need to add `width:100%` on class `.topnav.responsive` at `600px` media width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set width:100% to class .topnav

```
.topnav {
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%; /*newly added*/
}
```